# Blocking operation in Qt Quick

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to perform a long task when a button is clicked. I want this task to block the UI, because the application cannot function until the task is done. However, I want to indicate to the user that something is happening, so I have a `BusyIndicator` (that runs on the render thread) and is set to display before the operation begins. However, it never renders. Why?

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDebug>

class Task : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool running READ running NOTIFY runningChanged)

public:
    Task() : mRunning(false) {}

    Q_INVOKABLE void run() {
        qDebug() << "setting running property to true";
        mRunning = true;
        emit runningChanged();

        // Try to ensure that the scene graph has time to begin the busy indicator
        // animation on the render thread.
        Q_ASSERT(QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "doRun", Qt::QueuedConnection));
    }

    bool running() const {
        return mRunning;
    }

signals:
    void runningChanged();

private:
    Q_INVOKABLE void doRun() {
        qDebug() << "beginning long, blocking operation";
        QDateTime start = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
        while (start.secsTo(QDateTime::currentDateTime()) < 2) {
            // Wait...
        }
        qDebug() << "finished long, blocking operation";

        qDebug() << "setting running property to false";
        mRunning = false;
        emit runningChanged();
    }

    bool mRunning;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    Task task;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("task", &task);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import Qt.labs.controls 1.0

Window {
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Shortcut {
        sequence: "Ctrl+Q"
        onActivated: Qt.quit()
    }

    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 20

        Button {
            text: task.running ? "Running task" : "Run task"
            onClicked: task.run()
        }
        BusyIndicator {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            running: task.running
            onRunningChanged: print("BusyIndicator running =", running)
        }
    }
}
```

The debugging output looks correct in terms of the order of events:

```
setting running property to true
qml: BusyIndicator running = true
beginning long, blocking operation
finished long, blocking operation
setting running property to false
qml: BusyIndicator running = false
```

Comment: I just don't get why you insist on locking the main thread? Just use a worker thread and block events to the UI while it executes. Most OS will give you an "application is not responding" if you block the main thread, usually ask the user to terminate or terminate straight away.

Comment: I'm using the GUI thread because I don't need to switch to a separate thread yet. I haven't experienced the "application not responding" message.

Comment: Unless it is an op that involves UI elements, you can and definitely should do it asynchronously via a worker thread. Rule of thumb is every operation that takes longer than 25 msec should be handled this way. You don't get "not responding" because you know what happens and you stay away from touching the application, as soon as an input event which the OS fails to deliver to the application event loop occurs, you will get it. Definitely not something you'd want to pass to a client.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, thanks. I'll consider doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoking a function with `Qt::QueuedConnection` doesn't guarantee that the `BusyIndicator` has had the chance to begin animating. It merely [guarantees that](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum):

> The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread.

[Another solution](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details) that might sound promising is `QTimer::singleShot()`:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(doRun()));
```

> As a special case, a QTimer with a timeout of 0 will time out as soon as all the events in the window system's event queue have been processed. This can be used to do heavy work while providing a snappy user interface [...]

However, this also won't work. I'm not sure why. It could be that, internally, the rendering/animation is not done via a queued invocation, and so the timeout happens too early.

You could specify an arbitrary amount of time to wait:

```
QTimer::singleShot(10, this, SLOT(doRun()));
```

This will work, but it's not that nice; it's just guessing.

What you need is a [reliable way](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#afterSynchronizing) of knowing when the scene graph has begun the animation.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QQuickWindow>

class Task : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool running READ running NOTIFY runningChanged)

public:
    Task(QObject *parent = 0) :
        QObject(parent),
        mRunning(false) {
    }

signals:
    void runningChanged();

public slots:
    void run() {
        qDebug() << "setting running property to true";
        mRunning = true;
        emit runningChanged();

        QQmlApplicationEngine *engine = qobject_cast<QQmlApplicationEngine*>(parent());
        QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(engine->rootObjects().first());
        connect(window, SIGNAL(afterSynchronizing()), this, SLOT(doRun()));
    }

    bool running() const {
        return mRunning;
    }

private slots:
    void doRun() {
        qDebug() << "beginning long, blocking operation";
        QDateTime start = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
        while (start.secsTo(QDateTime::currentDateTime()) < 2) {
            // Wait...
        }
        qDebug() << "finished long, blocking operation";

        QQmlApplicationEngine *engine = qobject_cast<QQmlApplicationEngine*>(parent());
        QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(engine->rootObjects().first());
        disconnect(window, SIGNAL(afterSynchronizing()), this, SLOT(doRun()));

        qDebug() << "setting running property to false";
        mRunning = false;
        emit runningChanged();
    }

private:
    bool mRunning;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    Task task(&engine);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("task", &task);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import Qt.labs.controls 1.0

Window {
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Shortcut {
        sequence: "Ctrl+Q"
        onActivated: Qt.quit()
    }

    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 20

        Button {
            text: task.running ? "Running task" : "Run task"
            onClicked: task.run()
        }
        BusyIndicator {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            running: task.running
            onRunningChanged: print("BusyIndicator running =", running)
        }
    }
}
```

This solution relies on having access to the application window, which isn't *that* nice, but it eliminates any guesswork. Note that if we don't disconnect from the signal afterwards, it will continue to be called each time the scene graph has finished synchronising, so it's important to do this.

If you have several operations that will need this type of solution, consider creating a reusable class:

```
class BlockingTask : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool running READ running NOTIFY runningChanged)

public:
    BlockingTask(QQmlApplicationEngine *engine) :
        mEngine(engine),
        mRunning(false) {
    }

    bool running() const {
        return mRunning;
    }

signals:
    void runningChanged();

public slots:
    void run() {
        qDebug() << "setting running property to true";
        mRunning = true;
        emit runningChanged();

        QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(mEngine->rootObjects().first());
        connect(window, SIGNAL(afterSynchronizing()), this, SLOT(doRun()));
    }

protected:
    virtual void execute() = 0;

private slots:
    void doRun() {
        QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(mEngine->rootObjects().first());
        disconnect(window, SIGNAL(afterSynchronizing()), this, SLOT(doRun()));

        execute();

        qDebug() << "setting running property to false";
        mRunning = false;
        emit runningChanged();
    }

private:
    QQmlApplicationEngine *mEngine;
    bool mRunning;
};
```

Then, subclasses only have to worry about their logic:

```
class Task : public BlockingTask
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Task(QQmlApplicationEngine *engine) :
        BlockingTask(engine) {
    }

protected:
    void execute() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        qDebug() << "beginning long, blocking operation";
        QDateTime start = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
        while (start.secsTo(QDateTime::currentDateTime()) < 2) {
            // Wait...
        }
        qDebug() << "finished long, blocking operation";
    }
};
```

Comment: `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` guarantees FE not to block animations

Comment: Its use is discouraged: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents

Answer (score 1):

Most animations in QML depends on properties managed in the main thread and are thus blocked when the main UI thread is blocked. Look into  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animator.html for animations that can run when the main thread is blocked. If possible, I'd move the operation into another thread though, that's much simpler and also allows for e.g. cancellation of the operation from the UI.

Comment: [BusyIndicator](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/qquickbusyindicatorring.cpp) implements an `Animator` (this is what I meant when I said "runs on the render thread"), so that's not the problem here. I'm not sure that I agree with "much simpler". Can you alter the example I provided to demonstrate what you mean?